# How do you use the win_security_policy module for something in the local policies section using Ansible?

Tags: windows, ansible, hardening

I want to be able to modify certain local policies on my WS 2019. I've tried to use the win_security_policy module from ansible but it doesn't recognize the section "local policies". According to the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_security_policy_module.html#parameter-section), local policies is a section, I might be having trouble with my key and value but the error I get is the following:

```
The section 'Local Policies' does not exist in SecEdit.exe output ini
```

This is the policy I want to enabled: Devices:
[Prevent users from installing printer drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaqsi.png) located under Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local
Policies\Security Options

```
- name: test for local group policy editor
    win_security_policy:
    section: Local Policies
    key: Prevent users from installing printer drivers
    value: 1
```

I'm really not sure about the way I go about this, I didn't find any examples with this section in particular. Any help is appreciated!